# What is the best way for bilingual website in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, multilingual

I am new to SharePoint bilingual web-applications and I need to know what is the best practice/way to develop the website.

I am really not interested to use the SharePoint variation and getting two websites instead of one, and I want to build it using resources files and based on the selected language I can change the style also,

so the question is what is the best way to store the selected language, should I use cookies, query string or you can suggest something else for me?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure a lot of organizations use a third party software that quickly does what you are asking. www.pointfire.ca.

Comment: we don't need third-party software